# Drawing circle/rectangle is not working with javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

When I want to draw  a circle, its shows me a ellipse.
I have same problem with drawing rectangle, if I  put same width and height, it show me a width proper, but height is height/2. I'm unable to get the shape what I need. code :

```
c.beginPath();
c.arc(Vkrug.x, Vkrug.y, Vkrug.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
c.closePath();
c.fill();
```

and i get: `http://prntscr.com/aihuti`, 
   same with `http://prntscr.com/aihvdj`.

Comment: Include your HTML code.  It is likely that the problem is there.

Comment: i think i find it .... i cant give canvas width and height  from html.... must set attribute on it :) 

tnx alot <3

Comment: Sounds like you're using CSS to disproportionally resize your canvas -- that's causing your ellipse instead of circle problem. The fix is to either (1) always resize proportionally when using CSS -- multiply both the CSS width and height by the same scaling factor or (2) resize the canvas element itself: `c.canvas.width=400; c.canvas.height=200`.